# Recording/playback audio on web based page with Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I've found plenty in javascript etc, and for desktop-based ones in Java, but none for web-based java.  Any ideas?

Comment: Oh yeah, I love web pages playing sounds!

Answer (score 1):

For comprehensive access to the Java Sound API, look to the [javax.sound.sampled package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html).

See the [Sound Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) of the Java Tutorial for details on how to use the API.

To record sound, the applet would need to be digitally signed (by you) and trusted (by the end user - when prompted at start-up).

Daniel made a good point about sound in web pages.  Users generally hate it.  Make sure your applet does not attempt to play any sound until requested by the user.  Set the volume to a relatively low one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create an applet, which then is embedded into web page. And applets are capable of playing whatever you want, even without authorisation from the user (as far as I remember, it is allowed by JVM sandbox). Applet class even has dedicated method for this: Applet.newAudioClip .

Comment: A sand-boxed applet cannot record sound.  Imagine the 'web page that listens in on you' & sends everything it hears back to the server for analysis!